# Difficulty accessing checked items from checked list box

Tags: powershell

I have a function that creates a checked list box and I can not figure how to get hold of the checked items.

The function that creates the checked list box is:

```
function  Add_ListBoxChecked ($name, $parent, $range, $dock, $x, $y, $length, $height){
    $object = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
    $object.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
    $object.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.size($length, $height)
    $object.Text = ""
    $object.CheckOnClick = $true
    $object.Dock = $dock
    $object.Items.AddRange($range)
    $variable = Get-Variable $name -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
    If ($variable -eq $null){
        New-Variable $name -Value $object -Scope global
        (Get-Variable $parent).Value.Controls.Add((Get-Variable $name).Value)
    }
    else {(Get-Variable $parent).Value.Controls.Add((Get-Variable $name).Value)}
}
```

The function that calls the creation of the check box is:

```
else {  
        if ((Get-Variable BuildList).Value.SelectedIndex -eq 1){
            $name = (Get-Variable CompaniesList).Value.Selecteditem + "name" + "Prod"
            $ListName = (Get-Variable CompaniesList).Value.Selecteditem
            $text = (Get-Variable CompaniesList).Value.Selecteditem + " " + (Get-Variable CurrentProdVersion).Value.Text
            Add_TabPage $name  CompaniesListTabControl 0 0 0 0 $text "none"
            Add_ListBoxChecked $ListName $name $ProdFiles "Fill" 0 0 100 100

        }
```

Any help on accessing the Checked Items would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried having the function pass `$object` back as output, and then call the function like `$chkListBox = Add_ListBoxChecked $ListName $name $ProdFiles "Fill" 0 0 100 100` ?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Sorry for the delayed reply, that would work great if I only ever had one tab page open at a time. Unfortunately I can have several tabs open at once and need to find a way of getting hold of the checked items of the active tab. Any further advice would be much appreciated.